# Parsing a path to get desired name

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a given path to a project or a package in the project such that I can construct a useful name from it.

I've been toying around with regex but I am having troubles.

Examples of what I want (`supplied string` => `desired one`):

```
"C:/Users/IDPWorkspace/moneyTestProject/bin"  => moneyTestProject
"C:/Users/IDPWorkspace/moneyTestProject/bin/moneyScenario" => moneyTestProject_moneyScenario
```

So far I've got

```
path.toString().substring(path.toString().indexOf("bin")+4)
               .replace('/', '.').replace('\\', '.');`
```

which does fine in getting everything past bin but not sure how to do the other stuff...

Comment: I know nothing of java but wouldn't it be just as easy to split string on `/` forward slash and remove indexes 0, 1, 2 and 4 or select indexes 3 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Java compiler available, but you can try this pseudo-ish code:

```
String[] delimiters = {"/", "\\"};
String[] tokens = path.Split(delimiters);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    if(tokens[i].toLower().equals("bin") && (i > 0))
    {
        result.append(tokens[i-1]);
        for(int j = i+1; j < tokens.Length; j++)
        {
            result.append("_" + tokens[j]);
        }
        break;
    }
}

String finalPath = result.toString();
```

Comment: Please change `tokens[i].toLower() == "bin"` to `tokens[i].toLower().equals("bin")`. I am allergic to comparing Strings with `==` even in pseudocode. Thanks :)

Comment: Good call! Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `/([^/]*)/bin/?(.*)` ? Replace with backreference 1 and 2 like so:

http://regex101.com/r/cZ4lM3

You would then need to strip a trailing _ in the case the 2 doesn't match. (Or test for 2 and join with _)